# Как на sql выбрать из столбца name фамилии, id которых не встречается в столбце chief

Tags: sql

Есть таблица вида:
CREATE table_name (id int, name varchar,chief int);
INSERT INTO table_name values (1, 'Иванов', NULL),(2, 'Петров', 1),(3, 'Сидоров', 2)

Необходимо выбрать сотрудников не являющихся ни чьими руководителями

Comment: Оптимальный способ выполнить задачу зависит от структуры таблиц (особенно наличия индексов) и их наполнения. Либо `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL`, либо `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. В большинстве случаев второй способ предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, таблица называется "workers". Тогда

```
SELECT chiefs.*
FROM workers AS chiefs -- взяли таблицу workers первый раз, это будут руководители
    LEFT JOIN workers AS slaves -- взяли таблицу workers второй раз, это будут подчинённые
        ON chiefs.id = slaves.chief
WHERE slaves.id IS NULL
```